# Stopping a Faucet From Leaking

Tags: water, hardware, sink

I finished using the sink to wash my hands when I realized that the faucet was not closed completely for some reason. Drops of water kept going out and my money will too due to the water bill. My dad is at work and it is a hassle to call some company to come home and help. Even more money would go down the sink through that...

What is a hack to stop your faucet from leaking?

Methods I've Tried:

- Duct Tape (Too Messy)
- Turning the Knobs a Certain Way (Faucet Won't Stop Dripping)
- Using my Un-Leaking-a-nator (Doesn't exist)
- Harnessing my superpowers (Don't Have Any)

*Note: A faucet may be known to you as a 'tap' if you're from the UK.*

Comment: If the faucet has a standard hose thread, you can get a plastic or metal hose cap for ~US$1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary fix is to use the shut-off valve under the sink.

A permanent fix would require taking the faucet apart. Sometimes cleaning pieces -- especially the washers -- will help the parts seal again, thus preventing dripping. However, more often, parts such as the washer or (depending on the type of faucet) must be replaced. This isn't generally difficult.

Note also that some brands of faucets have lifetime warranties. You can call their number, tell them what faucet you have and what isn't working, and they'll send you the parts for free.

Comment: I don't recommend using the valve under the sink, except to shut off so the faucet above can be fixed. Often times these have not been used or closed in a long time, and pliers may be need to twist them hard enough. Do not use the shut off valve as a substitute, but fix the faucet instead.

Comment: @subjectivist Thus why I say "A temporary fix".

Comment: @subjectivist if the shutoff valve doesn't work properly, then that should be replaced as well. There is no worse feeling than needing to use it and discovering that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Short of taking the faucet apart and replacing the seat or other assembly, often times working the handle will cause it to stop leaking. Buildup inside will prevent it from completely closing. Working it back and forth with force can break up deposits allowing it to seat correctly. If there is light to moderate corrosion this may still work, but with corrosion the seat or other assembly inside must be replaced.

Other than this there is nothing you can do for a leaky faucet except replace parts inside.

Comment: That was what I tried

Comment: Did you bump to either side very hard?

Comment: Yes, Yes I did without wrecking the handles

Comment: You need to take it apart and fix it.